# Jenkins: how to configure initial admin with ssh publickey by script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have this groovy script to initialize my Jenkins server:

```
def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false) ;
hudsonRealm.createAccount('admin','admin')
instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonRealm)
def strategy = new FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy()
instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)
```

This will create a "admin/admin" user at initial startup of my Jenkins instance.

How do I complete this to add my SSH public key to the user "admin"?

The objective is to be able to use the "ssh admin@jenkins" to run commands after the config, like explained here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/#ssh

PS: I know I can do it manually through the web interface, I am looking for a mean to do that by script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "Configuration as code", this is possible with this config:

```
jenkins:
  authorizationStrategy:
    loggedInUsersCanDoAnything:
      allowAnonymousRead: false
  securityRealm:
    local:
      allowsSignup: false
      users:
        - id: admin
          name: ${ADMIN_USER}
          password: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
          properties:
            - sshPublicKey:
                authorizedKeys: ${readFile:/conf/generated/authorized_keys}

security:
  sSHD:
    port: 22
```

See https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I found this set of scripts here: https://gist.github.com/nigimaster/6a014c62b444fe7a7744304d66881451

I post here the full commands with comments:

```
//
// Create initial admin with username/password = admin/password
//
//   thanks to https://gist.github.com/hayderimran7/50cb1244cc1e856873a4
//
def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false) ;
hudsonRealm.createAccount('admin','password')
instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonRealm)
def strategy = new FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy()
instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)
    
//
// Add ssh key to admin
//
//    thanks to @nigimaster https://gist.github.com/nigimaster/6a014c62b444fe7a7744304d66881451
//
def user = hudson.model.User.get('admin')
user.addProperty(new org.jenkinsci.main.modules.cli.auth.ssh.UserPropertyImpl(
    /** your public key content: ssh-rsa AA... */
))
user.save()
    
//
// Allow connection over ssh
//
//   thanks to https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins-infra/blob/staging/dist/profile/files/buildmaster/enable-ssh-port.groovy
//
def sshConfig = instance.getDescriptor('org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD')
sshConfig.port = 22
sshConfig.save()
```

This file is saved at /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/customize.groovy (at least in the docker file).

**Security advice:** you should parametrize your groovy file to **not** have the passwords stored in it. Public key should not be a problem.